# Ubuntu 16.04 - Ctrl and alt do not always respond

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Got a chance to install Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on a Dell XPS13. Most of the things look good, but switching from one workspace to another does not work nicely. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+(<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>) does not always move from one workspace to another. It seems that either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> is ignored at random points (used `xev` to check).

Even if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd> in some other applications (Emacs), they do not seem always responsive (e.g., when I go to the beginning of a document).

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you get the same result with a different keyboard?

Comment: Great question. I do not have any external keyboard at the moment, but I will test it this afternoon. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Glad to help! :-)

Comment: Checked. Everything works as expected with an external keyboard.

I tried using left Ctrl+Alt and right Ctrl+Alt and the result is the same; they do not always respond together the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand whether you expected it to work properly with an external keyboard or not. Can you clarify? Thank you.

Comment: My theory is that there is something wrong with the keyboard drivers for XPS13 (or some other setting). So, yes, I expected that things work fine with an external keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's driver related. The intermittent nature of your problem leads me to believe that that's highly unlikely. I had a similar issue with An Acer ASpire D270 netbook. The problems on that device also went away when I used an external keyboard. I permanently resolved the problem without any driver changes simply by replacing the faulty keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes debris can get under the key caps and interfere with proper operation, this can often be resolved with a can of compressed air.

Sometimes the switch under a keycap will begin to fail, causing intermittent failure.

Both of these issues can be resolved by using a different keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this out. It would be somewhat surprising, as I just got the laptop less than one week ago. Maybe I should try to install Windows back (I know it is a horrible idea) and check if things work as expected.